# Styling a div with ID inside a div with specific class

Tags: html, css

I have written a CSS file to style a div with ID, inside another div with Classes. It looks like this

```css
div.class1.class2 > div#ID1{
Styling Rules
}
```

But nothing is happening to DIV with ID1. Would appreciate any help and I can't change the structure of HTML or apply other IDs or classes to the elements.

```html
<div class="class1 class 2">
<div id="ID1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use .class1 #ID1 {Styling Rules} ?

Comment: Without your ([mcve]) HTML we can only say that the selector is wrong. If you show us your HTML we can tell you *why* it's wrong.

Comment: cause same css file is being used for backend and the frontend, and changing the ID1 itself produces inconsistencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs should only be used once, so if you followed that convention then you would simply target the ID in your selector and not concern yourself with the parent container it's in...

```
#id1 {
    // code
}
```

But because of what you're asking implies that you have an ID being used more than once, I would suggest changing this to a class before moving forward; however, if you still wanted to keep your HTML the way it is, then you need to do this...

```
.class1 #id1 {
    // code
}
```